# How to access third Nested ListView properties

Tags: c#, asp.net

Good Morning

I want to know how to get the ListView Control in this scenario:

```
<asp:ListView ID="lv1" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="lv1_ItemDataBound">
     <asp:ListView ID="lv2" runat="server">
           <asp:ListView ID="lv3" runat="server">

           </asp:ListView>
     </asp:ListView>
</asp:ListView>
```

in Codebehind:

```
protected void lv1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) {
    ListView lv2 = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lv2");  // Accessed
    ListView lv3 = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lv3");  // Not Accessed (NULL)
}
```

I'm trying to access the nested last one from the parent ListView. Any advice please. ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using the ItemDataBound event of lv2 to get lv3

```
protected void lv2_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) {
    ListView lv3 = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lv3");
}
```

Comment: You're right, I've to bind the each nested one in the right place with setting the OnItemDataBound Property.. Thanks for all also for helping

Answer (score 1):

Also, I don't believe you can nest `ListView's` like that.

it would be more like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ListView ID="ListView2" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:ListView ID="ListView3" runat="server"></asp:ListView>
        </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

But yes you can do as Josh W stated and use a series of `.FindControl()` calls

Comment: How can I use series FindControl? I tried but not gettin' the lv

Comment: ListView is a Databound control.  If ListView's are anything like GridView's, then in order for a ListView to be rendered, and therefore searched, it must have a DataSource and that DataSource has to return data, ad further each level of ListView must use a Key field from it's parent item.  So it depends on what you are trying to do.  In your example you are trying to do something in the ItemDatabound event, however all Listview's *will have their own* ItemDatabound event so you may not need to search 3 levels deep.  Are you sure you're addressing the right problem?

Answer (score 0):

this is a guess... as I have zero experience with asp, but your control should be accessible from your casted lv2 as lv3 is "inside" it.  I'm assuming the search only does a top-level check on the `ListViewItemEventArgs`

```
protected void lv1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e) {
    ListView lv2 = (ListView)e.Item.FindControl("lv2");  // Accessed
    ListView lv3 = (ListView)lv2.Item.FindControl("lv3");  // try it?
}
```

### EDIT

MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

> Use FindControl to access a control from a function in a code-behind
>   page, to access a control that is inside another container, or in
>   other circumstances where the target control is not directly
>   accessible to the caller. **This method will find a control only if the
>   control is directly contained by the specified container; that is, the
>   method does not search throughout a hierarchy of controls** within
>   controls. For information about how to find a control when you do not
>   know its immediate container, see How to: Access Server Controls by
>   ID.